# How to think about self-information?

Tags: intuition, information-theory

Recently, I've been struggling a bit with the concept of self-information. In particular, I don't know how I'm supposed to interpret an event "having more information" than another.

For instance, if I have a weighed coin such that $P(tails) = 0.9$ and $P(heads) = 0.1$, then

$$ I(tails) = \log_2\left(\frac{1}{0.9}\right) \approx 0.152 < 3.3219 \approx \log_2\left(\frac{1}{0.1}\right) = I(heads)  $$

So flipping the coin and getting heads "gives more information" than getting tails. However, in what sense is this the case? Like, what does getting heads give me more information *about*? Is it just a way to say that an event is "more surprising" than another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned "self-information" as "the surprise function", so this is definitely a way of quantifying that an event is more surprising. It ($s(A)=-\log_2\mathbb{P}(A)$) is the unique function that satisfies:

- $s(A)$ depends continuously on $A\mapsto \mathbb{P}(A)$
- $s(A)$ is decreasing in $A\mapsto \mathbb{P}(A)$
- $s(A\cap B)=s(A)+s(B)$ for independent $A,B$
- $s(A)=1$ if $\mathbb{P}(A)=0.5$
- $s(A)=2$ if $\mathbb{P}(A)=0.25$

Thinking about why each of these conditions are required and desirable (bar the last two, which fix the base and coefficient) gives insight into self-information.

To directly answer your question, though, there is a sense in which getting heads tells you more information than tails. Consider a crime scene where a sample of blood is tested and found to be a blood type that $10\%$ of the population have. This gives you more information than if the blood matched $90\%$ of the population. Information theory often works well through this "crime scene" lens of "narrowing down suspects".